# Paypal Express Checkout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, ACK = SUCCESS but error in response

Tags: paypal

We're getting a few transaction responses back from Paypal GetExpressCheckoutDetails which contain `ACK=SUCCESS`, but are in an error state.

We're doing between 10 and 50 transactions per day and we'll get 1 of these errors every couple of days.

Here's an example key/value of some of the response values:

```
'CHECKOUTSTATUS' => 'PaymentActionNotInitiated',
'TIMESTAMP' => '2016-12-04T11:46:16Z',
'CORRELATIONID' => '86c6e7942fd77',
'ACK' => 'Success',
'VERSION' => '124',
...
'PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE' => '13113',
'PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_SHORTMESSAGE' => 'Buyer Cannot Pay.',
'PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_LONGMESSAGE' => 'The Buyer cannot pay with PayPal for this Transaction.',
'PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_SEVERITYCODE' => 'Error',
```

This seems to be contradictory. There's nothing else within the response that looks wrong or implies an error.

Our code checks the `ACK` value (which seems to be the documented instructions). Does anyone else have any experience of this?  Should we be checking for this extra error key?